# Python 2.7 debugging basic code

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, numbers

So I submitted this for a Cousera course on basic python (I'm very very new to writing code). It worked. However, I found a bug in it (which I'm both glad I can see and heartbroken because it exists).

The problem is that if the smallest number in a string of numbers is the *first number* given it gets absorbed by the largest variable and not into the smallest variable. How would I prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance!

Code below:

```
    largest = -1
    smallest = None
    while True:
        try:
            num = raw_input('number\n')
            float(num)
            if num > largest:
                largest = num
            elif smallest is None:
                smallest = num
            elif smallest > num:
                smallest = num
        except:
            if num =="Done":
                print "Maximum is", largest
                print "Minimum is", smallest
                break
            print "Invalid input"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of programming!

Usually when I do min/max comparisons, I start with negative and positive infinity and not None/null or the first element of the list as that has given me headaches in the past.

This code seems to work fine to me.

```
largest = float("-inf")
smallest = float("inf")

while True:
    try:
        num = raw_input('number: ')
        num = float(num) # I reassign num for good-measure
        if num > largest:
            largest = num
        if num < smallest:
            smallest = num
    except:
        if num == "Done":
            print "Maximum is", largest
            print "Minimum is", smallest
            break
        print "Invalid input"
```

Comment: reassigning num isn't just good measure, it's necessary! the OP's example of `float(num)` converts the input to a float and then discards that float immediately!

Comment: @turbulencetoo - Python variables aren't typed and he called just `float(num)` without reassignment to have it throw an exception down to the sentinel block. I did it so decimal numbers couldn't be interpreted and compared as strings.

Comment: I'm surprised to learn that there is a `>` defined that lets you compare between `str` and `int`, usually python is strict about those sorts of comparisons.

Comment: Nvm I guess I'm just used to python3 where these comparisons are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Purely as an educational exercise, you could use some of python's features (`generators`) to make this code more generic.

This creates a generator called `numbers` which returns a sequence of input numbers, that is collected as a list in `a` and then you can use the builtin `min(a)`, `max(a)` methods:

```
def numbers():
    while True:
        try:
            num = input('number\n')
            yield float(num)
        except ValueError:
            if num == "Done":
                break
            print "Invalid input"

a = list(numbers())
print "Maximum is", max(a)
print "Minimum is", min(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this by setting smallest and largest to the first number input, and doing this before your while loop. That way, for every new number you see, you can update the values of smallest and largest depending on its relative magnitude. Something like this:

```
largest = -1
smallest = None

try:
    num1 = raw_input('number\n')
    smallest = num1
    largest = num1

    while True:
        num = raw_input('number\n')
        num = float(num)
        if num > largest:
            largest = num
        elif smallest > num:
            smallest = num
    except:
        if num =="Done":
            print "Maximum is", largest
            print "Minimum is", smallest
            break
        print "Invalid input"
```